# Amazon API: How do I use Amazon's MWS API to get product information using ASIN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

As of Jan 23, 2019, Amazon has limited the use of Product Advertising API. Now, I am trying to write a script that can fetch product information using ASIN using their official APIs.

How can I use MWS API for this purpose? And what are the differences between the Product Advertising API and MWS API?

Comment: I would suspect if they removed the functionality from one API they don't intend to make it available in another.

Comment: Are you a professional seller or has another seller authorized you to develop for them?  If so, you'll have access to MWS and you can read all about it here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/.   The PA API is meant to allow you to sell and advertise amazon's products on your own site.  MWS is for you to sell your own products on Amazon.

Comment: MWS can only be used to access your products. AFAIK, we can't access products from other suppliers using the MWS API. That's why I am looking at the Product Advertising API. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, here's what I found:

Product Advertising API (PA API) is offered by Amazon to get product information with `POST` requests. However, the throttle limit depends upon the affiliate sales made by your account in the last month [as of 23rd Jan 2019].
You won't be able to make any request if you have zero sales. In that case, the only way to pull data is scraping.

MWS API (available to sellers) on the other hand can only be used to retrieve your products only. You can't use MWS API to get product information from other suppliers.